# How can I check if a sorted subarray with size 'k' , is contained in an bigger sorted array with size 'n' (k <= n) this complexity O(logn)?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, time-complexity, sub-array

I would like to find if a sorted subarray v' with size 'k' is contained in another sorted array with size 'n'. We know that k <= n. However, it would be so easy with a double for loop or something similar, however I would like to implement it with complexity O (logn).

For example, for v = [-10,-3,0,**4,7,19**,33] and v' = [**4,7,19**] it would say TRUE.

Could someone help me??????????

Comment: If the array to be searched is not already sorted, it is impossible to do this in O(logn) ... without a quantum computer

Comment: It seems that there is no way to do it in logarithmic complexity

Comment: @ControlAltDel sorry sorry. I forgot to say they are sorted. Would you know then how to do it???????????

Comment: Neither the array nor the subarray in your example are sorted.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes they are. Look it

Comment: You can do a binary search on the array to be search using the first value you are looking for O(logn). If found, check that the next n values match.

Comment: I think linear search part after the binary search is more complicated than `n` values.   The following is a sub array that should return `true`.   `Array = 1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12` `sub array = 5,5,5,5,6,7,8`   It is dependent upon from which value of `5` the linear search is started.

Comment: Once you state that both arrays are sorted, this seems to me to be similar to `String.contains.`  but also being able to take advantage of the binary search as suggested.  You may want to check the source for the String method to get some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do better than binary searching the *n*-sized array for the first item of the *k*-sized array and then verifying all of the *k* items are in the larger array in O(*k*) time. (You do not specify whether there must not be extra items between the *k* items; I am assuming that there must not be).

The running time of doing this depends on the relative sizes of *n* and *k*. If *n* is much larger than *k* then the binary search will dominate the running time, if not the linear search will. It is essentially `O( max(log(n), k) )`.